# Stanford ner java.lang.OutofMemory issue and interpretations of the outputs

Tags: java, out-of-memory, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to use stanford-ner.jar to train on a relatively large corpus (504MB) and even though I use the option of -Xms1g and -Xms1g there's still memory issues. And what's horrible (I assume) is the output, when I tried to train a small model, the output is like:

```
[1000][2000]numFeatures = 215032
```

However, the staff I got currently is even up to "534700" and numberFeatures is still being computed. I think there must be something wrong that cause the memory issue that the software can't handle such large features? And I don't really understand the [1000][2000].. what does these mean? Is there a tutorial by Stanford explaining the outputs of the software ?

My train corpus' format is like：

```
Google    COMP
And       O
Steve     PER
.         O

Microsoft COMP
Facebook  COMP
Total     MET
profix    MET
.         MET
```

Things like that, small entries that all make this 504MB corpus.

Can anyone points me the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably increase the memory allocated to the program. What is the `-mx` value you pass to Java? `-Xms` sets the initial memory, whereas `-mx` (or `-Xmx`) sets the maximum memory. My guess would be that for a corpus of 500MB, this has to be a very large value -- at minimum a few 10GB, and possibly more. On top of that, I have a bad feeling this will take very long to train.

Where did you collect such a large training corpus from? Is it possible to subsample the corpus, at least initially, and see if that trains?

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion. I added the -Xms and -Xmx even to 50GB (the aws has a lot..) but it still didn't work. The corpus was generated by simulation program and the subsample can be trained...